# Manage one Python project for different platform?

Tags: python, selenium, project-management

I have a python project, which I hope it to run both Mac OSX and Raspbian(Raspberry pi).

In this case, I want to know how I can manage my project(whole scripts) for both platform?

I know that most codes are platform-independent, but some codes, like selenium, are platform dependent. Why?

The reason is like this :

My program is crawling certain web page and collecting data headlessly.

I use my Raspberry with just ssh and so only command line interface is available.

I use PhantomJS on Max OSX. But PhantomJS is difficult and complex to install in Raspberry pi.

So, I have to use different `webdriver` for both cases.

In Mac OSX,

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

In Raspbian,

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But managing two discrete python projects (one for Mac OSX, the other for Raspbian) is kinda irratating..

If I insert the codes something like below to deal with it,

```
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
elif platform.system() =='Darwin':      # Mac OSX
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

everytime the code be changed, I have to transfer whole project file to my Raspberry pi, which is very irritating.

How could I deal with it effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the code into several files:
1. rasp.py

```
def raspberry_run():    
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

2. mac.py

   def mac_run():

   ```
   browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
   ```
3. main.py

import platform

from mac import *

from rasp import *

if platform.system() == 'Linux':

```
raspberry_run()
```

elif platform.system() =='Darwin':

```
mac_run()
```

Every time you change the mac.py or raps.py, you don't need to change the main.py.

Answer (score 0):

I routinely develop on multiple platforms over the course of the day and there's just no substitute for a good cloud-based source control tool like [github](https://github.com/).

With simple push and pull commands you have one place to access your files from with the safety and security of an off-premise backup copy. Not to mention having your full revision history at your fingertips.

By only managing your source code (and package requirements in something like [pip's requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)) there; you're free to customize your environments in any way you need to, such as installing platform specific libraries.